# How to set more than one potential arguments for Keyword Element Should Contain from SeleniumLibrary in Robot Framework

Tags: parameter-passing, robotframework

Could anyone help me with the following situation:

I need to check the value of a status cell in a table on a web page that can potentially have one of several different values (strings), for example: *imported*, *done*, *failed*.

I am using the keyword *Element Should Contain* from the SeleniumLibrary and would like to validate as a positive result, if the value is either *imported*, or *done*.

So far I only know how to check only for one of those, for example for *imported*, by using as an argument for the expected result - *imported*, however I need that in both cases, either imported or done, to be considered as passed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can use for your purpose something like the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


Test Teardown  Close Browser


*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}          Chrome
${URL}              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679739/how-to-set-more-than-one-potential-arguments-for-keyword-element-should-contain
${ELEMENT_LOCATOR}  //*[contains(text(), 'Ask Question')]
${EXPECTED TEXT 1}  Ask Question
${EXPECTED TEXT 2}  Anything else


*** Test Cases ***
Test with two acceptable values
    Open Browser  url=${URL}
    ...           browser=${BROWSER}
    ${element}=   Get webElement  locator=${ELEMENT_LOCATOR}
    ${bool_result}=  Set variable if  '${element.text}' == '${EXPECTED TEXT 1}' or '${element.text}' == '${EXPECTED TEXT 2}'
    ...                                ${True}
    ...                                ${False}
    Should be true  ${bool_result}
    ...             msg=Expected that element with locator '${ELEMENT_LOCATOR}' contains text '${EXPECTED TEXT 1}' or '${EXPECTED TEXT 2}', but got '${element.text}'
    Close Browser
```

Here I've just created the boolean variable with the result of the comparison of my element's text and the acceptable two values (${EXPECTED TEXT 1} and ${EXPECTED TEXT 2}).